# How to validate a moment.js duration?

Tags: momentjs, duration

It seems like only a moment() object has a isValid() method to check the validity of the provided data. Is there any equivalent for the moment.duration() object? Because isValid() does not seem to exist on durations.

Comment: Maybe you can use [`moment.isDuration(obj);`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/is-a-duration/)

Comment: what do you consider a valid duration ?

Comment: moment.duration('5 of my personal duration units') should be invalid for example

Comment: moment.isDuration only checks, whether obj is of type duration. it does not check if it is valid.

Comment: you are bringing your own logic into this, and you are not being all that clear about it. `moment.duration('5 of my personal duration units')` would return a valid duration object with a duration of 0 because `'5 of my personal duration units'` is not recognized by moment as a valid measurement, what you can do, is validate the measurement string you pass it, and the numeric value and then test for `.isDuration`... maybe!

Comment: Hm, but that is exactly my point, moment() has a isValid method, that would be invalid if provide an invalid input. duration returns a duration of 0, which is neither consistent nor helpful

Comment: An example of what would be invalid would be `moment.duration(5, 'mintes')` or  `moment.duration('foo')`. Having it return 0 in this situation means you have a bug that is way hard to find. It's not very difficult to come up with some invalid input, be it some unsupported units (not likely) or a simple typo. In my opinion its already gone too far if you are calling the `isValid` method. It should have thrown or returned undefined by then.

Answer (score 2):

I agree this seems to be an omission in moment. I have come up with the following workaround method of validating durations since I had the need. The insight is that an invalid duration, results an a duration that is exactly 'P0D'. Just sharing that here:

```
durationIsValid(iso8601DurationString){
  if(iso8601DurationString === 'P0D') return true;
  return moment.duration(iso8601DurationString).toISOString() !== 'P0D';
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This won't work if you're intentionally creating a zero-length duration. When moment gets invalid duration units, it defaults to zero. So this will give you a false negative in that case. (The current moment version is 2.20.1 at the time of this comment. Hopefully there will be better duration validation in a future version). The relevant validation is in this module: https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/develop/src/lib/duration/constructor.js

Answer (score 0):

In case of ISO8601 parsing, I suggest trying to parse it usign `moment.duration(myIso8601Duration)`, get ISO8601 string from it again, using `toISOString`, and then compare it with `myIso8601Duration`. If they differs, input may be invalid.

Comment: This doesn't work P2W3DT4H5M6S is valid and the same as P17DT4H5M6S which is what is spit out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Moment 2.29. It's easy to test for validity *if* your use case has a minimum valid length of the duration.  For example, `dur.isValid() && dur.as("minutes") >= 1` covers typographical errors, using `NaN` as numeric input, passing an invalid ISO8601 string, etc, because all those cases result in a zero-length duration.  (If zero-length durations actually make sense for your use case, look to the other answers for guidance... but they probably don't.)